# UIImageViews added to UIScollView never get deallocated, Memory Leak?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, dealloc

This is my first post and you are my last hope.

I have a list with images in my iPad app, if you select one, my class `MyViewController` which extends `UIViewController` is loaded and shown (by just setting `window.rootViewController`, by using `UINavigationController`, by `presentModalViewController` - tried everything, doesn't make any difference). It has a `UIScrollView` inside, which adds a big version of the image to the `UIScrollView` with this code:

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[delegate getImageNames] objectAtIndex:(gameNr*2)]]];
tempImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,tempImageView.frame.size.width/2,tempImageView.frame.size.height/2);
[self setMyImage:tempImageView];
[tempImageView release];

myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myImage.frame.size.width, myImage.frame.size.height);
myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
myScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
myScrollView.bounces = NO;
myScrollView.delegate = self;
[myScrollView addSubview: myImage];
```

`myImage` is a `(nonatomic, retain)` property of the type `UIImageView` inside my `MyViewController`.

After pressing a button and go back to the list of images, I release the reference to `MyViewController` and it's dealloc method is called like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    CFShow(@"dealloc!");
    for(UIImageView *subview in [myScrollView subviews]) {
        if(subview.frame.size.width > 20){
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            [subview setImage:nil];
        }
    }

    [myImage setImage:nil];

    self.myScrollView = nil;
    self.myImage = nil;

    [myScrollView release];
    [myImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

It works so far, but the problem is, that the memory of the images is not really deallocated this way. After opening and closing about 12 images, the app crashes with memory warning. 
This is also confirmed by the report_memory method I got from here:
[iOS Low Memory Crash, but very low memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980636/ios-low-memory-crash-but-very-low-memory-usage)

The dealloc method IS called, that's triple checked. 
I checked the variables `myImage` and `myScrollView`via breakpoint in the debugger, they are set to 0x0 by those commands in the `dealloc` method. Why is the memory not freed????????

Thanks for any suggestion, I am working on this since three whole days, it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
self.myScrollView = nil;
self.myImage = nil;

[myScrollView release];
[myImage release];
```

with this:

```
[myScrollView release];

self.myScrollView = nil;
self.myImage = nil;
```

And post code where you define property `myScrollView` and `init` it.

And you don't need loop `for(UIImageView *subview in [myScrollView subviews])`. When you will `release` `myScrollView` object it will automatically release all its subviews.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. 

Changing the code like you wrote leads to a crash: 
-[UIImageView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1c1320

Here the code you asked for in .h:

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;
    ...
    }
    
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;
    ...

As you see, I did not call alloc myself, because it is loaded in a nib file. 

May this be the problem?

Greetings

Michael

Comment: If I don't add the images to the scrollview, I have no memory problem, yes.