# iPhone app crash randomly with signal 9

Tags: iphone, crash

I have an app which crashes randomly on different scenario and logs is as follows

```
Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x55fb]) Exited: Killed
Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0xa13c]) Exited: Killed
Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.MyApp.app[0x137]) Exited: Killed
Mon Jul 16 22:00:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (com.apple.accessoryd) Exited: Killed
Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'Mail' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed
Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal (15%). Delaying auto-relaunch of 'Mail' for 30 seconds.
Mon Jul 16 22:00:41 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'app' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed
Mon Jul 16 22:00:42 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'Phone' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed
```

Comment: Looks like you have a bigger problem with mail than your app (which I assume is com.MyApp.app - incidently, MyApp is not a great name for a company!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app crash because of low memory.You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980636/ios-low-memory-crash-but-very-low-memory-usage) to calculate memory use :)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting low memory crash. Use Instrument to evaluate your memory usage.